# Why can't Android Studio detect my phone?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am making a simple Android App, and I wanna connect my computer with my phone. However, when I connect it, it couldn't detect that. I clicked the troubleshoot button, it re-scanned my USB device, it found these:

1. Generic USB Hub (0x8087)
2. Generic USB Hub (0x8087)
3. Generic USB Hub  (0x8087)
4. Generic USB Hub (0x8087)
5. Integrated Camera (0x17EF)
6. **LG K10 LTE (0x1004)**
7. TouchChip Fingerprint Coprocessor (0x147E)
8. USB  Composite Device (0x17EF)
9. USB Composite Device (0x17EF)
10. USB Root Hub ()
11. USB Root Hub ()
12. USB Root Hub ()
13. USB Root Hub ()

What should I do?

I have already done the following procedures:

- Enabled USB debugging
- Changed MTP into PTP

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when you connect your phone to pc, you see a dialog that asks you to give the pc access to the device data - try to accept this dialog and see if android studio will recognize your phone now.

In addition, if this won't work try to change the  USB setting to the transfer Files option and check again

Answer (score 0):

Set your USB mode to "Transfer Files" or "File Transfer," then check Android studio again.

There should be an item in your notification drawer that lets you set the USB mode.

Answer (score 0):

There might be several possible reasons. As your device is shown as a connected USB device, I suppose the driver is already installed for that device to be discovered by your computer.

In that case, I would like to suggest to check if the `adb` is installed or not. If not, please install the `adb` and run the following command to check if the device is detected.

```
adb devices
```

I would like to recommend you going through [this tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/) as well where you will find some other insights on how you can solve your problem.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this method, it worked for me at least.

Download adb driver from [here](https://androiddatahost.com/293a2)

Install adb driver, it's gonna prompt you to install adb system-wide and I suggest you do so. After installation, go to device manager and search for your phone.
Right-click it and choose update driver-->Browse my computer for driver software-->Let me pick from a list of available drivers on my computer-->Select adb driver/adb device from the list then click install. Hope this works for you, good luck.